# dictionary counts timestamps wrong

Tags: python, dictionary, timestamp

So I have a list with timestamps, here are a few:

```
 lst_selected_uuid_timestamp=
 [datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 29, 15, 49, 33),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 29, 15, 49, 36),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 29, 15, 49, 36),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 29, 15, 49, 37),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 29, 15, 49, 37),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 29, 15, 49, 37),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 29, 15, 49, 37)]
```

I create a dictionary with 24 hours, 60 minutes per hour and 60 seconds per minute as key/values

```
# Create dict with 24 hours, 60 minutes per hour and 60 seconds per minute

dict_timestamp_seconds = {}

for second in range(0, 60):
    dict_timestamp_seconds[second] = 0

dict_timestamp_minutes = {}

for minute in range(0, 60):
    dict_timestamp_minutes[minute] = dict_timestamp_seconds

dict_timestamp_hours = {}

for hour in range(0, 24):
    dict_timestamp_hours[hour] = dict_timestamp_minutes

# pprint(dict_timestamp_hours)
print("success")
```

I create another dictionary, which is a copy of the one made above (in case something messes up), where I add 1 at the right hour, minute, second.

```
dict_test = {}
dict_test = dict_timestamp_hours

for index in range(0, len(lst_selected_uuid_timestamp)): # go through each timestamp
    timestamp = lst_selected_uuid_timestamp[index] # get timestamp

    hour = timestamp.hour #get hour in timestamp
    minute = timestamp.minute # get minutes in timestamp
    second = timestamp.second #get seconds in timestamp

    if timestamp.day == 29: # filter on day 29
#         print(type(hour))
#         print(type(minute))
#         print(type(second))
        print(hour, minute, second) #print hour, minutes and seconds
#         if hour == 15 and minute == 49 and second == 33:
        dict_test[hour][minute][second] += 1 # add 1 to that hour at that minute at that second
```

For some reason it doesn't count right. The code below should print the value 1, but it prints 18. It seems to add 1 whenever it sees the second 33.

```
print(dict_test[15][49][33])
```

I don't understand why this happens. Could someone explain why this is?

Please ask if I need to give more context, this is my first post.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the main issue is related to the fact that you did a shallow copy of the dictionaries.

Shallow copy:

```
dictionary = {}
a = dictionary
b = dictionary 
# a and b are the same object
a["x"] = 3
b["x"] = 4
print(a["x"]) # prints 4
```

When you do

```
for minute in range(0, 60):
    dict_timestamp_minutes[minute] = dict_timestamp_seconds
```

it means that you're assigning the same seconds' timestamp to ALL the minutes' timestamp's entries.

Solve using a deep copy:

```
from copy import deepcopy
...

for minute in range(0, 60):
    dict_timestamp_minutes[minute] = deepcopy(dict_timestamp_seconds)
    # This creates a deepcopy of the object, means that it is a 
    # different object that is not bounded with the original one.
```

If you want to create different timestamps you have to apply the deepcopy to every copy you're trying to make.